# QT Web Assembly cache

Tags: qt, webassembly

Работает ли QNetworkDiskCache для QNetworkAccessManager в Web Assembly?

Я использую файловую систему IDBFS. Директория для кэша создаётся, но кэш в нее не добавляется. В обычной, desktop версии, кэш работает нормально. В версии для веба кэш вообще поддерживается, или придётся его вручную делать?

```
auto _networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
auto _diskCache = new QNetworkDiskCache(this);
_diskCache->setCacheDirectory(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::CacheLocation) + "/image_cache");
_networkManager->setCache(_diskCache);
QUrl imageUrl(id);
QNetworkRequest request(imageUrl); 
QNetworkReply* reply = _networkManager->get(request);
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [this]() {
  auto pReply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply*>(sender());
  if (pReply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
    QByteArray imageData = pReply->readAll();
    _image.loadFromData(imageData);
  }
  emit finished();
});
```